# No Matching ABI Error when deploying Blazor Hybrid App

Tags: .net, blazor-webassembly, .net-maui, maui-blazor

We are attempting to run a Blazor Hybrid app (BlazorMaui project referencing a Blazor WASM project which is run on startup in a BlazorWebView component) on a physical android device and are running into problems.

Whilst this works in an emulator, when the signed APK is uploaded to browserstack, the installation of the app fails with the following error:

**Install Failed, No matching ABIs.**

We have tried experimenting with different build settings to change supported architectures and we still receive the same error.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Had you tried to test it on different devices? Did you set it supporting all the architectures such as arm64, arm, x86 and so on.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I've tried it with many different devices and seems to be the same for all of them.

Comment: Had you tried to set the supporting architectures in the .csproj file?